# I feel like I missed out on fundamental mathematics and want to start from the beginning? Should I start with Khan Academy or something else?

Tags: education

I am trying to backtrack and remember my math classes throughout my academic life and can only remember a time in 5th grade where I started subtracting from left to right. Somehow I also completely missed the fractions lesson in grade school and even today (sophomore in college) I struggle with fractions.

I am learning proofs now and the most difficult part for me is honestly the arithmetic. I can follow formulas and rules but when it comes to mathematical creativity, logic, and reasoning, I fall behind. It seems I am at least 2 minutes behind each topic in class when trying to understand the material compared to the rest of my classmates.

I want to develop a deep mathematical thinking and maturity and feel the best way to do is by filling in the gaps from the beginning (because I am not sure where all the gaps are).

I thought I could start with Khan Academy. Is this a good resource to accomplish this or should I look elsewhere?

Comment: I feel I cannot give suitable suggestion, but I want to wish you best luck. There might be a long way to go, and things might get difficult sometimes. But it is good that you decide to start the journey. So no matter what, do not give up, and just keep going, and enjoy the beauty of math!

Comment: @YujieZha thank you for the push! I started with kindergarten math today during coding breaks and I can't believe I got a few wrong already. I have to pay attention to sloppiness. I'm going to have fun with this. Thanks for your your comment!

Comment: That's good, and always remember we have a whole community here to answer questions too! @seerocode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fundamental arithmetic, Khan Academy is the best, hands down. Although once you reach really complicated things, other resources online may prove to be better/faster, Khan Academy has absolutely everything you need. Even if you just do early math (Kindergarten - 5th, arithmetic, some fractions) it is extremely thorough. [This link](https://www.khanacademy.org/math) shows you the breakdown, and you can just go through the exercises (there are close to 500 types, each with 5+ problems).